# fopen mlock access violation

Tags: c++, fopen

I'm repeatedly getting the same error exception for the following method.
Unhandled exception at 0x77a8f4e1 in AST.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x29919ed9.

```
bool package::write(char * buf, size_t size, const char *fname)
{
   //makeDir(fname);
   FILE * output = fopen(fname, "wb");//break point
   if (output == NULL)//break point
   {
      perror("ERROR: ");
      return false;
   }
   fwrite(buf, size, sizeof(char), output);
   fclose(output);
   return true;
}
```

It has something to do with the fopen, I know that because of breakpoints. But it only gets the exception the four time it's used, no matter what I do. I've changed the the fname repeatedly, but it always crashes the forth time it's used. And for some reason after I click "Break", I end up at the 345th line of mlock.c.

I'd really appreciate any help in fixing this really annoying headache of an error.

Comment: Show the complete calling code.

Comment: It can be what ever, this is the last test one I used. pkg.write("Hello, bitches!", 16, "output/dummy");

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple complete example written in C that can be trivially converted to C++ showing the correct way to write your function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int write( char * buffer, size_t bytes, const char * name )
{

   FILE * output = fopen( name, "wb");

   if ( !output )
   {
       perror( "ERROR" );
       return 0;
   }

   fwrite( buffer, sizeof( char ), bytes, output);

   fclose( output );
   return 1;
}

int main( )
{
    write( "Hello world!", strlen( "Hello world!" ), "output.txt" );

    return 0;
}
```

You were calling `fwrite()` with the wrong order of arguments. The 2nd parameter is the size in bytes of each element to be written to your buffer. The 3rd parameter is the total number of elements to be written to the buffer. For reference, see [`fwrite()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/).

You should specify an extension when creating a file with `fwrite()`. Otherwise, the system will create a file of generic type.

It isn't necessary to add a colon and a space after the string passed as an argument to `perror()` The function does this for you. For reference, see [`perror()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/perror/)

Comment: This has to do with the fopen, but the fwrite. I have already switched the fwrite parameters and it's still the same.

Comment: There should not be anything wrong with the fopen() call. The only way it would be crashing on fopen() is if you are abusing the function. I had no problems running the code above. Try running my code and see if an output.txt file appears in your program's directory.

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem down.

Write a program that calls your function four times in a row. If that does not fail then you know the problem is somewhere else.

You can either add more of your original program to the test program, or begin subtracting pieces of your original program. Back it up first, or commit it to source code control.

When you have things that act so strangely like this seems to be doing, it is very likely that the problem is somewhere completely different. Your program might be writing into memory that it doesn't own. For example, if part of the program holds a pointer to an object and that object gets deleted, and then mlock allocates and reuses that memory *AND THEN* the program uses that old pointer, it would be writing over mlock information, causing the crash.